# Get value of selected multiselect attribute

Tags: attributes, product-attribute, multiselect-attribute

Take the following "car" product: **Volkswagen Golf**.

It has a multiselect attribute `car_options` with the following possible options and their ids:

- Airco (id=123) **selected**
- Radio (id=124) **selected**
- Bluetooth (id=125)
- Navigation (id=126)

Radio and Airco are selected for this product. How can I get those two values (radio, airco) and display them? $_product is given.

Answer (score 21):

Try this:

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('car_options')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: I get no output! This is not a dropdown, but a multiselect attribute!

Comment: It should still work with a multiselect, I just tried it myself. Try `var_dump($_product->getData('car_options');` and check the output. It should be a comma separated string, if it's not then I can only imagine a 3rd party module is interfering.

Comment: Still no output. We use several modules, but I don't know of any that messes with the attributes.

Comment: If `$_product->getData('car_options')` returns NULL, it means it's not added to your product collection. We will need to know more about where you are trying to access this attribute

Comment: I've found a solution - see my answer.

Comment: Your solution is just very bad code. It can work but it's extremely slow. The solution above *is* the right solution, you just need to make sure your attribute is part of the product collection. Don't go for dirty because it's quicker.

Comment: Your code works in the template/catalog/product/view.phtml page, but not in the list.phtml page. How do I make the attribute part of the product collection? Isn't an attribute always part of a product?

Comment: Edit your attribute and in the Frontend Properties section, set `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes`. It will make the attribute selectable in product listings.

Comment: That's the way to do it - thx!

Comment: Thanks @Mayers, the solution is too good not to override the existing getAttributeText:
```
     public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)  
     {
        return $this->getResource()
            ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
            ->getFrontend()
            ->getValue($this);
     }
```

Comment: @Mayers And what about if you want this attribute on related.phtml or somewhere else where there is no product collection used.

Comment: >> Your code works in the template/catalog/product/view.phtml page -- not over here. Magernto 1.9.4.x ..... value is empty

Answer (score 2):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$attributevalues= $product->getResource()->getAttributeRawValue($product_id,'my_custom_attribute_code',$storeid);
```

it works.. Hope it help you..

Comment: Awesome...It works like a charm!!!!!

Comment: glad to know :) @SnehaPanchal

Answer (score 0):

The following code

1. returns the value ids of the selected options for this product: **123,124**
2. turns that into an array: **array(123,124)**
3. then finds the label of those options: **123=>Airco** and **124=>Radio**
4. and returns the values in a text string: **Airco, Radio**

```
$_attribute_code = 'car_options';
$car_options_csv = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, $_attribute_code, $storeId); // returns: 123,124
$car_options = explode(',', $car_options_csv);
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product',$_attribute_code);
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute ->getSource()->getAllOptions();

$res = '';
foreach($attributeOptions as $a)
{
    $l = $a['label'];
    $m = $a['value'];
    if (strlen(trim($l))>0 && in_array($m, $car_options))
    {
        $res .= trim($l) . ', ';
    }
}
echo substr($res, 0, -2);;
```

Comment: Ouch - you don't usually wanna go down that road. Especially since Mayer's answer above works fine.

I'm also not sure if you're not bypassing Magento's translation system this way - haven't checked though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mayers, his solution is too good not to override the native getAttributeText:

```
 public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)  
 {
    return $this->getResource()
        ->getAttribute($attributeCode)
        ->getFrontend()
        ->getValue($this);
 }
```

and to add to the customer model as well.